# Backup failed in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

If I am using `BACKUP` statement:

```
BACKUP DATABASE [Database name]
TO DISK = ‘Location’
WITH INIT, NOSKIP, NOFORMAT
```

Backup did work. But if I am trying to use same query in a stored procedure like

```
SET @SQLCMD = N'BACKUP DATABASE [Database Name] TO DISK = ''' + @FILENAME + ''' WITH INIT,NOSKIP, NOFORMAT' 

EXEC (@SQLCMD)
```

I am getting error message:

> Msg 203, Level 16, State 2, Procedure sp_BackupDatabase, Line 31
>   The name 'BACKUP DATABASE [Database Name] TO DISK =
>   'C:\Users\PC\Desktop\Backup\20121008\db.bak' WITH INIT,NOSKIP,
>   NOFORMAT' is not a valid identifier.

I couldn't figure out where I am making error.

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sir what you are doing executes the command as a stored procedure and ofcourse it's not a valid identifier for the name of the stored procedure! So I recommend you to use `"sp_executesql"` instead. If your code works fine, it should work everywhere else.

Referring to [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175170(v=sql.105).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175170%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Like this code:

```
Declare @Command    Nvarchar(500);

Select  @Command    =   N'BACKUP DATABASE [Database Name] TO DISK = ''' + @FILENAME + ''' WITH INIT,NOSKIP, NOFORMAT';

Execute sp_executesql   @Command
```

Cheers

Comment: Can you explain about sp_execute bit more.

Comment: Sorry that I mentioned sp_execute. Actually it's sp_executesql and it does the same as "Exec" (or Execute) keyword. It executes specified statement with optional parameters. See update. Cheers

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Now, if I am using sp_executesql I am getting error message "Procedure or function 'sp_executesql' expects parameter '@statement', which was not supplied". What does that mans?

Comment: Don't be sorry, it's ok sir. That message does mean that you have a problem passing @Command to the procedure. Could you please show me what you wrote? just the line of executing procedure. Thanks.

Comment: It's working now. I did little bit of research on the link which you had provided and I was able to work with that. Thanks for your help.